# How to write this xml code in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-styles, android-studio-2.3

I'm very new to Android Studio. As a beginner I have created a simple app containing a custom_button.xml file in "res/drawable" folder.

**custom_button.xml code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
<shape android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/colorDarkGrey"/> <!-- default color -->
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

and activity_main.xml file have two custom button

**activity_main.xml code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/1"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton2"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:text="@string/2"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"/>  <!-- How to change default color ? -->

</LinearLayout>
```

So My problem is that how can I change the MyButton2 (button ID) default background color using custom_button.xml file.
I know that I can create one more drawable xml file to change the MyButton2 color but I want to use  custom_button.xml file to change the default color.
 Please help me guys !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
     android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

in button you want to change

Answer (score 0):

This will change background drawable color dynamically.

set background color like this

```
setBackground(MyButton1,Color.BLUE); // you can set any color here
setBackground(MyButton2,Color.GREEN);

private void setBackground(View view,int color) {
    Drawable defaultDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(YourActivity.this, R.drawable.custom_button);
    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(defaultDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable,color);
    view.setBackground(wrapDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. I created the shape programmatically. for example:

```
 GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        shape.setColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
        shape.setStroke(4, android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#111111"));
        shape.setCornerRadius(50);
        btnCac.setBackground(shape);
```